# WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified when creat subprocess

Tags: python-2.7

win 7

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNdPS.jpg)

python 2.7

this error occurs when I was trying to creat the subprocess.

```
cmd += "\dld_tool -c {} -F {} -d {} -r {}".format(dldcom, ffile, dfile, 
 pfile)


    startupinfo = None
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

    is_starting = False
    process = Popen(cmd, startupinfo=startupinfo, stdout=PIPE)

    q = Queue()
    t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(process.stdout, q))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    t0 = time.time()
    cnt = 1
```

Comment: Post you python code that creates the process.

Comment: What is the executable and the arguments? What is the value of cmd at the line of Popen? Does the executable actually exists?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so that we can reproduce your error. By just posting a snippet from your code we can't help you.